# Brightness settings not working on Aspire E1-571G

Tags: brightness

When I try to adjust the brightness bar in 'Brightness & Lock' in system settings. There is absolutely no change.

Is there some other way that I can configure my screen brightness other than in Brightness and Lock setting?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file /etc/default/grub

Change the line:
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"

and then save and then run:
sudo update-grub

Then restart the computer, then it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try to navigate there via the CLI in etc/default there is no 'grub' only 'grub.d' is this the correct one and how do I open it? I tried to cd to it and got the message "grub.d: No such file or directory"

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu you are using? eg. 12.04 32 bit.